# Remove hover style on Kendo-UI Pie Chart

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, pie-chart

When the user hovers on the kendo-UI pie chart, each slice has a hover effect that i'd like to take off. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but check this configuration property: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.highlight.visible

Set `series.highlight.visible` to `false` to remove the hover ("highlight") effect.